# Definition of Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

In lecture notes that were handed out to me, a Galois extension is defined to be a field extension where one of the following equivalent statements holds:

1. $F$ is the fixed field of $\text{Gal}(E:F)$ is $E$
2. $F = (F^*)^{\circ}$
3. The only elements fixed by $\sigma\in \text{Gal}(E:F)$ are $F$ elements.

**My problem is with the third statement.**

If the third statement where true, then if we have an intermediate field of the extension $E:F$ we would have to have always that $K^* = \text{Gal}(E:K) = \{\text{Id}\}$, which is obviously false.

Does anyone perhaps know what the lecturer was trying to say for statement $3$? Or is it actually correct and I am missing something?

Comment: Does it means to say that the only elements fixed by *every* $\sigma\in \mathrm{Gal}(E:F)$ are elements of $F$? If not, that is very likely what it is meant to say, because as stated, it's false.

Comment: I see what is meant now, the wording was not clear in the notes.